# How to remove one line from repository with sed

Tags: command-line, repository, text-processing, sed

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains this line :

```
deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xenlism-wildfire/repo deb/
```

I want to remove that line via `sed` in command line, so I tried this code but returns error !

```
$ sudo sed 's:deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xenlism-wildfire/repo deb/::g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sed: -e expression #1, char 75: unknown option to `s'
```

I guess the symbol `:` after `http` caused this error, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use any* symbol to delimit the search/replace strings which does not conflict with symbols *in* the strings, as long as you use it consistently, e.g.:

```
sudo sed 's#deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xenlism-wildfire/repo deb/##g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This reduces the need to escape a problematic character (which could be done using `\` as an escape).

*I am sure there are exceptions, especially if using older versions of `sed`, but I'm not aware of any limitations off hand.

Answer (score 6):

Run like this:

```
sudo sed -i '\%^deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/xenlism-wildfire/repo deb%d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The problems I fixed:

- Use `-i` flag to modify the file in-place. Without that, the command would just print the output of `sed` to the screen, without updating the file.
- Instead of using `s///` to replace the line with empty string, I used the `d` command to delete the line.
- For the pattern matching, instead of `/.../`, I used `\%...%`, because `%` doesn't appear in the pattern. With `/`, all occurrences of `/` would have to be replaced.

Note that possibly a simpler filter might be good enough. For example if you know that `xenlist-wildfire` is unique in the file, then this simpler command will work too:

```
sudo sed -i '/xenlism-wildfire/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Since in this example there is no `/`, I could use the simpler `/.../` filter.

*(Thanks for [@steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) for the improvement ideas.)*

Comment: Good points @steeldriver, I improved my answer. Btw, even with the `s` command he could have used a simpler pattern, as `/xenlism-wildfire/s/.*//`. Not sure it's worth mentioning though, user seems to be a beginner.